# Is it true that summation of ideals equal to ideal generated by their generator

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose we have a family of sets $A_i \subset R$. Is it true that $\sum(A_i)=(\cup A_i)$. Brackets means ideal generation.

Comment: Yes, it is true.  It might be easier for you to understand if you write out the definitions.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just trying to get some confirmation since I didn't see this mentioned anywhere in my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $a \in A_i$ for some $i$, is $a \in \sum(A_i)$? Letting $a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n \in \sum (A_i)$. Is $a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n \in (\cup A_i)$? Why is this sufficient to argue that your claim is true?